# Looping through user input and reversing character array in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to get a user's input with a `while` loop as a character array (this array can have a maximum  length of 255 characters). Here is what I have so far, but nothing happens once I press enter after entering data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char inputString[255];

    printf("Enter a line of text up to 255 characters\n");

    int i = 0;
    while(i <= 255) {
        scanf(" %c", inputString);
        i++;
    }

    // Display Reversed String
    int x;
    for(x = 255; x >= 0; --x) {
        printf("%c", inputString[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to C and don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Thanks in advanced.

Eg: "`Hello World!`" should print "`!dlroW olleH`"

Comment: [sample to fis](http://ideone.com/UFEPOy)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this works, but im required to use a While loop (instead of the first for loop). However, my implementation does not work.

Comment: Loop does not matter `while-loop` even `for-loop`. (The pattern is the for-loop. such as second loop.) `" %c"` to skip the white space.(In a non-pointed part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it except for two things

1. The indices in c go from `0` to `N - 1`, so instead of

   ```
   int i = 0;
   while(i <= 255) {
   ```

   it should be

   ```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(inputString) ; ++i) {
   ```

   as you can see the loop goes from `i == 0` to `i == 254` or `i < 255` and not `i <= 255`. The same goes for the reverse loop, it should start at `sizeof(inputString) - 1` or `254`.

   Be careful using the `sizeof` operator.
2. You have to pass the address to the next character.

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &inputString[i]);
   ```

A better way to do this would be

```
int next;
next = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; ((i < sizeof(inputString) - 1) && ((next = getchar()) != EOF)) ; ++i)
    inputString[i] = next;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What is wrong or "skeptical" about using sizeof? And would this be its length?

Comment: `sizeof` is not used to compute the length of strings, just read the correct documentation. In this case it's used because `inputString` is an array and `sizeof` gives the number of bytes in the array, since each element in the array is a single byte, it's ok. But it wouldn't be enough if it were `int inputString[100]`.

Comment: You should probably emphasize that the more important change is from `<=` to `<`; the `sizeof` change is good too, but the 255 wasn't actually wrong.  You've missed that the output loop generally starts too late; it should be `for (x = i; x >= 0; x--)`.

Comment: @iharob Even with this code, after i press enter, nothing happens. Still looking for something wrong...

Comment: Because the code is not expecting you to press enter. What operating system are you working with?

Comment: @iharob I am on Windows 7 using CodeBlocks as my IDE.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Z instead of enter, does it work that way? And since you are using the gcc compiler why don't you move to a good OS like Linux or BSD?

Comment: @iharob This is a homework project (which is why im trying to get more knowledge on the why instead of the code being written for me). Because of that, I just use my windows machine.

Comment: I don't see how on thing relates to the other, Windows is fine if it works for you, I would feel like a 90% drop in productivity using it. So I recommended that because you will feel very comfortable writing code on a good OS. But that's clearly opinion based, so let's leave it here please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91895/discussion-between-fear-code-and-iharob).

Comment: Do it the way I showed. You'll either get an A or get expelled for cheating :-)

Answer (score 0):

This accepts arbitrary length input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll {
    struct ll *next, *prev;
    char c;
} ll_t;

ll_t *
newll() {
    ll_t *rv;
    if ((rv = calloc(sizeof (ll_t), 1)) != NULL)
        return rv;      
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory, fatal\n");
    exit(-1);
}

int 
main()
{
    ll_t *llp = newll();
    printf("Enter text to put in reverse order: ");
    while((llp->c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (llp->c == '\n')
            break;
        llp->next = newll();    
        llp->next->prev = llp;
        llp = llp->next;
    }
    for( ; llp != NULL; llp = llp->prev) 
        putchar(llp->c);
    putchar('\n');
}
```